# Keras model to focus on different metrics?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, tensorflow

When using the `model.compile()` attribute, does it matter what metric I place in there? For example, would `model.complie(metric='accuracy')` focus on increasing accuracy vs `model.compile(metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.Precision()])` focusing on Precision? Or do these just state what shows during the epoch training?

Answer (score 2):

Here are [the docs](https://keras.io/api/models/model_training_apis/#compile-method) for the `Model.compile` method.

The `loss` parameter is the objective function whereas the `metrics` parameter is a "list of metrics to be evaluated by the model during training and testing".

So your second interpretation is correct.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!